# R read_excel failed to open file

Tags: r, readxl

I get an error when running this code

```
file.lista <- list.files(pattern="*.xls")
dados_lista <- lapply(file.lista, read_excel)
```

> Error in read_fun(path = path, sheet_i = sheet, limits = limits, shim
>   = shim,  :    Failed to open Corínthia.xls

It's related with the file name, files with with characters like í, é, á ... on the name

last time i've runned this code I didn't had problems like this!

Can you help me finding the problem?

Since last time I've istalled tidyverse package and I've installed Git Bash, is it related...?

Comment: I think try importing library gdata for importing .XLS files. It should resolve your issue.Also add encoding="utf-8" while importing the excel file.